# Python Tkinter Menu System. Unable to get prices totaled and displayed

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

New to python & I have been tryna to build a small Menu with Tkinter, my idea is when I select an item from the menu the name of it appears in the larger screen and the total of the items selected appears in the smaller screen, my function is called fireFood. I'm currently seeing my prices run on a line instead of being totaled and I've been stuck on this for a couple days, hope someone can point me in the right direction.

```
rom tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x300')
root.title('Server Window')
root.wm_resizable(width=False, height=False)

# Create display area for selected items

display = tk.Text(root, height=10, width=30, bg='Orange', bd=4)
display.grid(row=1, column=3)

price_display = tk.Text(root, height=3, width=15, bg='Orange', bd=4)
price_display.grid(row=3, column=3)
#====================== Functions =================================
def fireFood():
    # Every time a new item is selected i want a new total to be calculated and displayed
    global menu
    global price_display
    global display
    global select_option
    total = 0
    prices = []
    # this inserts food item onto display
    display.insert(tk.END,options.get())
    prices.append([options.get(), menu[options.get()]])

    for x in prices:
        total = total + float(x[1])

    # this shows price on lower display
        price_display.insert(tk.END, total)

    total += float(menu[options.get()])

def addList(arr):
    cost = 0
    arr.remove('\n')
    total = [sum(float(x) for x in arr)]
    for x in total:
        cost += x
    return cost
#======================================================================

# Create a Dictionary of items to be displayed in Combobox
menu = {'fries ':5, 'Burger ':10, 'Pizza ':15, 'Chicken ':8, 'Fish ':7.50}
menu_list = [x for x in menu.keys()]
menu_prices = [y for y in menu.values()]
options = ttk.Combobox(values=menu_list)

# Set default value for the combobox to 'Menu' to function as a pseudo label
options.set('Menu')
options.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Create a button that when pressed will get the value of combobox
select_option = ttk.Button(root, text='Select', command=fireFood)
select_option.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should the `price_display.insert(tk.END, total)` be inside the `for` loop? Try taking outside of the loop.

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: Can you please post some minimal working code that we can test? It's easier to debug code when you can run it :D

Comment: Yea, definitely about to do that now. I've tried numerous implementations, this is my most recent effort

Comment: What is the use of the `prices` variable? From what I understand, moving `prices = []` to the start of the script nearly solved the problem. Can you please try it? Also I noticed that you never use the `addList` function.

Comment: `Total` is set to 0 every time `fireFood` is called. Define `total` outside the function.

Comment: I originally had the functionality encapsulated in that addList function. The prices var is me trying a different approach, but it isn't needed as my intention is just to get the total

Comment: @Raphael Mapp does this not solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no it does not.

Comment: What else do you need it to do?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```py
price_display = tk.Text(root, height=3, width=15, bg='Orange', bd=4)
price_display.grid(row=3, column=3)

total = 0

#====================== Functions =================================
def fireFood():
    # Every time a new item is selected i want a new total to be calculated and displayed
    global menu
    global price_display
    global display
    global select_option
    global prices
    global total # make total global
    prices = []
    # this inserts food item onto display
    display.insert(tk.END,options.get())

    # this shows price on lower display
    total += float(menu[options.get()])
    price_display.delete('1.0', 'end') # delete previous text
    price_display.insert(tk.END, total)
```

Comment: Thanks Derek, this solved my issue. Many thanks again.

Comment: Happy coding @Raphael Mapp